# When explicitly loading an embedded framework on iOS through code, alloc and class returns nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, dlopen

I am using an embedded framework which does swizzling and other things in its `+load` methods.

I need finer control as in to which situations the framework as actually loaded (I don't always use it).

In order to manually load it - what I have tried to do is remove the framework from the "embedded binaries" section.

The framework is now linked as "optional" rather than "required" (This is trial and error - what is the difference?)

Explicitly copying the framework to the application resources (not to the frameworks directory as the "embedded binaries" section does).

[image]

[image]

In my code I am only loading the framework when I actually need to use it by doing the following (is it correct to load using dlopen in this fashion?):

```
#import <MyFramework/MyFramework.h>
- (void)someplaceWhichNeedsToUseTheFramework 
{
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [self loadFrameworkDynamic:@"TheFramework"];
  });
  // do something with framework


  //>>>>>>>>>>>> This is the problem
  // Does not work!
  SomeClassFromFramework *obj = [SomeClassFromFramework alloc] init]; 
  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< 
  // Instead I must use the runtime syntax which does work. Why is this?


Class theClass = NSClassFromString(@"SomeClassFromFramework");
    [[theClass alloc] init];

// I've tried using the ordinary syntax again after this point but still not working
  SomeClassFromFramework *obj2 = [SomeClassFromFramework alloc] init]; // <<<<<<< still nil!
}

- (void)loadFrameworkDynamic:(NSString *)libName
{
  //WidgetSource is the name of framework

  NSString *libExtension = @"framework";
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:libName ofType:libExtension];
  NSLog(@"Loading dynamic library: %@", path);
  path=[path stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",libName]];

  void *revealLib = NULL;
  revealLib = dlopen([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], RTLD_NOW);

  if (revealLib == NULL)
  {
    char *error = dlerror();
    NSLog(@"dlopen error: %s", error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. Since you are loading that code at runtime, you must use the runtime syntax to access it. To make it easier to use, you might want to wrap that code in your own class that is always compiled in, and forward messages to the dynamically loaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Swift class name is qualified by the module in which it is compiled.
Prefix your swift class name with the name of the framework that you have dlopen'ed. Just the framework name without the extension, not the app bundle name.

`Class theClass = NClassFromString(@"TheFramework.SomeClassFromFramework");`